# How can I change this code so that it task scheduler can run it as a .vbs file?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have some vba code that sends an email with an attachment. it currently exists as a vba project in excel, but I would like to be able to save it as a vbs script so that I can fire it off every night with task scheduler. It only works in the project module I assume because I have to add a reference to an outlook library. If I save the script in notepad as a .vbs, it doesn't run.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SendBasicEmail()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olEmail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With olEmail 

        .Display
        .Attachments.Add "FileDirectory"
        .To = "my email"
        .Subject = "Subject"
        .Send

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can use it from a service but if you save this code into a text file with .vbs extension, this code will do the same as your Excel VBA version:

```
Option Explicit

Const olMailItem = 0

Sub SendBasicEmail()
    Dim olApp: Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim olEmail: Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With olEmail 
        .Display
        .Attachments.Add "FileDirectory"
        .To = "my email"
        .Subject = "Subject"
        .Send
    End With
End Sub

SendBasicEmail
```

The main differences:

- You cannot reference the Outlook library statically, so you have to use CreateObject
- Since missing the library, you have to look up the values of constants (e.g. olMailItem)
- You cannot declare your variables as of certain type, you can give them a name only and they will be all Variants.
- You have to call this Sub directly, e.g. at the end of the file rather than from a button's event handler

Comment: Perfect. This worked. I will have to tinker around and see if I can get it to work with a service.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook, or any other Office app, cannot be used in a service (such as the Scheduler).

Comment: The script I have works when I run it from inside the VB project in excel. If I copy the code into a text editor and save it as a .vbs file, I get a compile error when I try to open it.

Comment: What is the **exact** compile error?